# Pebble JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pebble-watch, cloudpebble

i am currently writing a watch app for my pebble time steel and are struggling as i try to introduce time synchronization. basically my code so far has all my lessons imported in as variables and i have an if-else statement to decide what day it is.

```
main.on('click', 'select', function(e) {
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
if (n == '1' ){
var h = d.getHours();
console.log(h);
var hm1 = 'm' + h;
console.log (hm1);
[hm1].show();
 }
```

This is only some of the code and i have had it work with just 'lesson1.show' before. i know the console logs are not necessary but they are useful for trouble shooting (sometimes;D).

```
var m9 = new UI.Card();
m9.title('Lesson 1');
m9.subtitle('Maths');
m9.body('08:55 - 09:54');
```

This is how i have the days laid out, from my illeducated mind this seems it would work but it doesn't. All i get is:

```
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: Timetable:343 21
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: Timetable:345 m21
[PHONE] pebble-app.js:?: Timetable:2221 JavaScript Error:
TypeError: [hm1].show is not a function
at null.<anonymous> (app.js:235:23)
at emitToHandlers (lib/emitter.js:121:17)
at Emitter.emit (lib/emitter.js:141:35)
at Window._emit (ui/window.js:274:12)
at Function.Window.emit (ui/window.js:286:17)
at Function.Window.emitClick (ui/window.js:301:17)
at Object.SimplyPebble.onPacket (ui/simply-pebble.js:1436:14)
at Array.SimplyPebble.onAppMessage (ui/simply-pebble.js:1480:18)
at Object.PebbleEventListener.dispatchEvent (webview_startup.js:143:50)
```

Any help is appreciated :D

Comment: You could possibly start with the actual error: ```[hm1].show is not a function```.  From what you posted above, ```hm1``` looks like you are using as an Array because of ```[hm1]``` and Array types don't have a method ```.show()```.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Based on the pebble.js documentation https://developer.pebble.com/docs/pebblejs/  I am guessing what you want to do is actually create a ```UI.card``` (or something else from the sdk) object type using their SDK.  Then use the .show() method on that object.

Comment: yes i have already done this and am fairly confident with this, my issue was using a variable as the name of the ui card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is looking for a similar issue use the eval statement this helped combide the variables as a javascript function

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). I would flag this post for deletion, but I'm out of flags...